# FacebookClient.Get("/page_name/feed") always returns only 25 latest posts

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I get posts by this code:

```
 facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
 var url = string.Format("/{0}/feed", pageName);
 IDictionary<string, object> feed = facebookClient.Get(url) as dynamic;
 JsonArray posts = feed.First().Value as dynamic;
```

I've tried to get posts of several pages (Coca-Cola for example) - the code always returns only 25 latest posts. How to get all the posts?

Answer (score 1):

So in addition to the post by Zharro saying to use the parameter values of limit and offset, you can also feed the next and previous paging values into the .Get method:

```
dynamic object = fbClient.Get("query/address", new {
     limit = ##
     offset = ##
});
...
Facebook.Get(object.paging.next) // Or Facebook.Get(object.paging.previous)
```

Note: Setting the limit value very high will just be ignored (e.g. setting limit to 10,000 won't actually give you 10,000 values even if there are 10,000 feed values).  You need to use either offset or query on the paging addresses.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to add `&limit=30` to the url you have (`/{0}/feed`) you should see 30 posts (I didn't test it today but it worked until a week ago...It should still work). 
So maybe you need to add a variable to build a different url. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No it desn't. If to specify a limit in this way: 
`dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.limit = 50;
parameters.offset = offset;`
and make requests in a loop - it woks almost good, but anyway DOESN'T load all the posts - at some point, for some reason it returns an empty response...

Comment: well I tested it and https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  with this url MyUserid/feed?limit=50 it gives you some results. Then it says "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/MYID/feed?limit=50&since=1378036233",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/MYID/feed?limit=50&until=1376928537" is this what you're looking for?
  }

Comment: okay I had read things about paging and have retrieved it for you https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/. I hope it's what you were looking for. I've never done it (I tend to use the limit the other way around...)